# Appending Data Frame's data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames, and I want to create a new data frame object with the data of all data frames.

I do not need to check any duplicity, since I do not have repetition of data, but I cannot find a function to append data from a data frame to another.

I tryed to use the merge functions as follows, with no sucess:

*folds* is a list() where each element is a data frame, all with the same structure but different data.

```
  #Copies the structure to a new Object
  trainingSub <- folds[[1]][0,]
  #append data
  for(y in 1:K){
    if(y!=i){
      trainingSub <- merge(trainingSub,folds[[y]],all=TRUE)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at `rbindlist` in the data.table package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you are looking for the classic:

```
do.call(rbind, folds)
```

which will append a list of `data.frame`s together by row.

If you need to combine by column instead, the approach would be:

```
do.call(cbind, folds)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
do.call(rbind,folds)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `rbindlist`:

```
library(data.table)
xmpl <- list(data.frame(a = 1:3),
             data.frame(a = 4:6),
             data.frame(a = 7:9))

rbindlist(xmpl)
#    a
# 1: 1
# 2: 2
# 3: 3
# 4: 4
# 5: 5
# 6: 6
# 7: 7
# 8: 8
# 9: 9
```

`rbindlist` is faster, but less flexible than the `do.call` approach. There is no `rbindlist` equivalent for quickly doing a `cbind`.

Comment: Note: that function requires the `data.table` package.

Comment: dayne, in what way do you mean less flexible?

Comment: dayne, so does `do.call`.. no?

Comment: @Arun Sorry. I was typing that on my phone this morning, and did not finish my thought. Then the page reloaded and I did not think it posted.

Comment: @Arun Really, the functionality that `rbindlist` will not handle is a list of vectors. `rbindlist` requires a list of data.table of data.frame objects, so I have ended up having to use the `do.call(rbind, ...)` method when working with a list of vectors. There is also no equivalent for `cbind`. It was not meant to be a knock on `rbindlist` -- it's my preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` and `plyr` alternatives to the other great approaches listed here:

```
# Using dplyr
library(dplyr)
data.frame(rbind_all(folds))

# Using plyr
library(plyr)
data.frame(rbind.fill(folds))
```

These both perform the same function as `do.call()` with `rbind` but offer some performance improvements.

Benchmarks:

```
folds <- NULL
for (i in 1:2000) {
    folds[[i]] <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
}

system.time({ x1 <- do.call(rbind, folds) })
#   user  system elapsed
#   1.11    0.00    1.10

system.time({ x2 <- data.frame(dplyr::rbind_all(folds)) })
#   user  system elapsed
#   0.05    0.00    0.05

system.time({ x3 <- data.frame(plyr::rbind.fill(folds)) })
#   user  system elapsed
#   0.53    0.00    0.54

system.time({ x4 <- data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(folds)) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Proof that they all yield the same result:

```
identical(x1, x2)
# TRUE
identical(x1, x3)
# TRUE
identical(x1, x4)
# TRUE
```